# Please help writing script that finds file with longest filename

Tags: shell-script, scripting

I'm attempting to create a script that loops through an entire directory of files in order to find the file with the most characters in that directory. Attached is my code sample. What am I doing wrong?

```
  1 #!/bin/bash
  2 #This program takes an array of files and sees which is the largest in a directory
  3 
  4 files=() #create an Empty array for which files will be stored
  5 longest=${files[0]} #Sets point of origin for the current largest file at 0
  6 
  7 echo "Enter Directory name:"
  8 read dir_name
  9 
 10 if [ -d "$dir_name" ]; then #Test file to see if it's a directory
 11 
 12         for i in "$dir_name"/* #For loop to discern the file with the most characters
 13            do
 14                 files=$dir_name
 15                 if [ "${#i}" -gt "${#longest}" ]; then
 16                         longest="$i"
 17                         echo "$i && Character count:${#files[i]}"
 18                 fi
 19            done
 20 
 21 elif [ ! -d "$dir_name" ]
 22 then
 23         echo "Sorry not the directory we are looking for"
 24         exit 0
 25 fi
 26 
 27
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see several errors in your code:

1. In your `for` loop you do not have a `do` at the beginning and a `done` at the end.
2. If you are writing `if [ ... ] then` in a single line you need to put `;` before the `then`.
3. You don't need to store the files in an array for the purposes of your script, you can iterate directly over the files in the directory

UPDATE: 
I have rewritten the script to do what you wanted it to do: get the file with the longest filename of the directory and print it with its character count:

```
#!/bin/bash

longest=0

if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then # if no argument given, read the directory from input
    echo -n "Enter directory name: "
    read dir_name
else
    dir_name=$1 # this allows execute the script with the directory as argument
fi

if [ -d "$dir_name" ]; then # process if what was given is a directory
    for file in "$dir_name"/* ; do
        if [ -f "$file" ]; then # do it only for files
            filename=$(basename $file) # get only the filename: NOT in all UNIX
            if [ ${#filename} -gt $longest ]; then
                longest=${#filename} # store new longest
                longest_file=$file # save the file
            fi
        fi
    done
    # we are done, print results
    echo -n "The file with longest filename is" $longest_file
    echo " with a filename" $longest "characters long"
fi
```

TEST:

given a directory "test" with the following regular files:

```
a ab abc abcd
```

the script's output looks like:

```
The file with longest filename is test/abcd with a filename 4 characters long
```

Comment: I'm kind of stuck at this point. and I know a lot of people are giving me thumbs down (well-deserved on my end). I'm trying to get my code to iterate through a directory that the User provides, then from there, check the length of each filename in that directory and at the end of the "For Iteration", returns the file with the largest file name alongside the character count of the filename. I'm not 100% sure what I'm doing wrong, I'm sure my code is close (though it's buggy).

Comment: I am seeing more things to correct in your script, if you give me a moment I will update my answer

Comment: Thanks Dave, I added a more recent correction to the script I formulated. Please give me your input.

Comment: @Linuxn00b see my updated answer, I provided a working script

Comment: Thanks Dave, you are really a hero, I appreciate it. Thank you very much once again.

Comment: @Linuxn00b you're welcome. if my answer solved your question, please accept it. Compare my script with yours in order to see the differences and learn something on the way ;)

Comment: I have went ahead and done so Dave, I'm just so upset with myself that I suck in comparison when writing shell scripts. I know that I'm still new to the process, but I want to be able to write shell scripts without any issues whatsoever. David, one other question, what is basename I noticed that you wrote it alongside $file. when declaring filename.